# Overwrite files of ftp server by batch

Tags: batch-file

I have this script to send files to my ftp:

```
@echo off
@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "%~dp0"
color 0a
mode 34,12
title Enviar Vendas Eco
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo            Sending ...
echo.
echo.
echo            Wait ...

( echo open ftp.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com
echo xxxxxxx
echo xxxxxx
echo ascii
echo prompt
echo cd "place1"
echo cd "place2"
echo lcd "%userprofile%\Desktop\test"
echo mput *.txt -overwrite
echo bye 
)> %temp%\ftpsend.dat
ftp -s:%temp%/ftpsend.dat >nul 2>nul
del /f /s /q %temp%\ftpsend.dat >nul 2>nul
exit
```

By default, the script would must overwrite the files if already exists on `.ftp`. But it isn't happening.

What is wrong on my script?

---

When i run appears the file was suceffully transfered, but it didn't replace the file that already exists on ftp.

Look the image:

[image]

Comment: What help file did you read that said there was an `-overwrite` option with the `FTP ` command?  Remove that.  By default prompting is on but maybe your FTP server is different.  I would issue a status command at the top of your script to see if it is on or off.

Comment: Looked at my FTP scripts.  I normally use the `-i` option and I don't use `prompt` in the script file.

Comment: `-i` or `prompt` do the same stuff. Anywaye the `overwrite` or `-o` i didn't find in the cmd help, but found in a website. But anyway, it doesn't worked. The file that is already in the ftp isn't beeing replaced.

Comment: Do the files overwrite when you manually transfer them with a GUI FTP client?

Comment: And how about capturing the output from the FTP command instead of sending everything to NUL.  That will most likely tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @Squashman look my edit. Just removed `echo off` and `nul` commands.